# ESLint Extra Parentheses In JSX

Tags: reactjs, jsx, eslint

I've noticed that extra parentheses are getting added to my multi-line conditional renders using logical AND (&&) in my jsx files. For example, this code from the React docs...

```
{unreadMessages.length > 0 &&
  <h2>
    You have {unreadMessages.length} unread messages.
  </h2>
}
```

...would get modified as follows:

```
{unreadMessages.length > 0 && (
  <h2>
    You have {unreadMessages.length} unread messages.
  </h2>
)}
```

[Here is my ESLint config](https://github.com/OriginProtocol/origin-dapp/blob/master/package.json#L108-L181):

```
"eslintConfig": {
  "root": true,
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true,
      "impliedStrict": true
    }
  },
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "es6": true,
    "mocha": true
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react"
  ],
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "computed-property-spacing": [
      "error"
    ],
    "indent": [
      "error",
      2
    ],
    "jsx-quotes": [
      "error"
    ],
    "key-spacing": [
      "error"
    ],
    "no-case-declarations": [
      "off"
    ],
    "no-console": [
      "off"
    ],
    "no-var": [
      "error"
    ],
    "object-curly-spacing": [
      "error",
      "always"
    ],
    "prefer-const": [
      "error"
    ],
    "quotes": [
      "error",
      "single",
      {
        "avoidEscape": true,
        "allowTemplateLiterals": true
      }
    ],
    "react/no-children-prop": "off",
    "react/prop-types": "off",
    "semi": [
      "error",
      "never"
    ]
  }
}
```

Have I inadvertently caused this, or is there a good reason for it? If not, how can I prevent this? It seems like overkill to [disallow unnecessary parentheses](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-extra-parens#disallow-unnecessary-parentheses-no-extra-parens).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is caused by [react/jsx-wrap-multilines](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/jsx-wrap-multilines.md) and can be prevented by setting the `logical` syntax type to `"ignore"`.